# Javascript - calculate position with iScroll

Tags: javascript, positioning, iscroll4

I have a pagination that needs to look like that:

[a busy cat http://img338.imageshack.us/img338/3180/pagination.jpg](http://img338.imageshack.us/img338/3180/pagination.jpg)

Basically, it's a div ( 20 000 px wide) inside another div that have a width of 160 with an overflow:hidden.

I used iScroll to make it scroll (im currently doing the iPad version of my site, so it have to works only on iPad) . So far it's working great, I can scroll in my div, and I need to "click" on the number to go to the page. And then the page reload.

My problem is that when my page load, the current page (the one in pink with a class="current") need to be in the middle of my div (like on the picture). So I need a way in javascript to do that...

For exemple, if I click on page 20, when the page loads, the pagination show the page from 1 to 10, if I scroll I can see that the page 20 is set as "current". Need a way to calculate the position and center it.

I have totally no idea on how to do that with javascript / jquery ...!

Can someone help?

Comment: Can you post the html of the whole scroll section?  Pretty impossible to do without knowing what you're working with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iScroll has a public method for this: `scrollToElement` – see the [docs](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4).

---

As an aside, the browser in iOS 5 supports scrolling natively with `overflow:auto;` and a special CSS declaration, `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;`.  I would use the native scrolling support instead of iScroll.